# Gap at DIV top and bottom even though margins are 0

Tags: html, css

I am using working on a HTML project and I am having some problems with displaying divs.

I created a "window" div that has a "windowContent" div inside. The "window" div has a border-image and the "windowContent" has just a white background.

The problem is that there is a gap at the top and at the bottom.

```
Result: http://i58.tinypic.com/35ckjk6.png
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/mp4a0do3/
```

I tried to set the margins to 0px, but still have the same problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Always post your code in the question please.

Comment: It’s called “adjoining margins” … the `margin-top` of the `h3` resp. the `margin-bottom` of the last `p` are merged with the margins of the surrounding `div` element.

Comment: I see. So the margin-top of the h3 is causing the problem. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS to remove the padding & margin of the first `H3` and the last `P` elements:

```
.windowContent :first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.windowContent :last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

(or, create new classes to do the same, and apply them to 2 same elements.)

Note that it is *very easy* to see where the gaps come from by inspecting elements using your browser developer tools (or Firebug on Firefox.)